# Python: Linear Regression of Subsets of Columns

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels, finance

I have a dataset of monthly stock returns that I am trying to regress on market returns by quarter and by company ID (PERMNO). Here's what the data looks like:

```
            date  PERMNO          MCAP    FIRMRF   MKTRF  qtr
0       2018-01-02   10026  2.784892e+06 -0.017514  0.0085    1
7339    2018-01-03   10026  2.757077e+06 -0.010048  0.0059    1
14671   2018-01-04   10026  2.795160e+06  0.013753  0.0042    1
22003   2018-01-05   10026  2.768464e+06 -0.009610  0.0066    1
29334   2018-01-08   10026  2.770518e+06  0.000682  0.0019    1
...            ...     ...           ...       ...     ...  ...
8455011 2022-03-25   93436  1.044531e+09 -0.003235  0.0027    1
8464495 2022-03-28   93436  1.128454e+09  0.080345  0.0073    1
8473980 2022-03-29   93436  1.136443e+09  0.007080  0.0145    1
8483469 2022-03-30   93436  1.130676e+09 -0.005075 -0.0083    1
8492959 2022-03-31   93436  1.113736e+09 -0.014982 -0.0155    1
```

The goal is to have the slope (beta) and standard error of each firm, each quarter, stored as values in the same dataframe (the quarterly regression values would be repeating for each line in a given quarter).

I've been scouring stackoverflow the past few days and have tried to repurpose a bunch of different answers here, but to no avail. So far, I'm assuming that it will need to look something like:

```
for i in daily['qtr']:
    for x in daily['PERMNO']:
        reg = sm.OLS(daily['FIRMRF'], sm.add_constant(daily['MKTRF']))
        results = reg.fit()
```

Any help, hints or advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of experimenting I've found a solution to the problem. I was able to define a function that contains the OLS regression and then apply it via a groupby function:

```
#Pull beta estimates
#Def Regression func
def regress(data, yvar, xvars):
    Y = data[yvar]
    X = sm.add_constant(data[xvars])
    result = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
    return result.params

#regression within group
params1 = data.groupby(['PERMNO', 'year', 'qtr']).apply(regress, 'FIRMRF', 'MKTRF')
params_raw = pd.DataFrame(params1)
params_raw.head(10)
```

Hopefully this will be useful to someone else!